# How to enable keyboard control of a menu when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Menu - Default functionality</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#menu" ).menu();
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-menu { width: 150px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
<li>Ada</li>
<li>Adamsville</li>
<li>Addyston</li>
<li>Delphi
<ul>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Ada</li>
  <li>Saarland</li>
  <li>Salzburg an der schönen Donau</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Saarland</li>
<li>Salzburg
<ul>
  <li>Delphi
    <ul>
      <li>Ada</li>
      <li>Saarland</li>
      <li>Salzburg</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Delphi
    <ul>
      <li>Ada</li>
      <li>Saarland</li>
      <li>Salzburg</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Perch</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-disabled">Amesville</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

How to make work the Jquery Keynav menu since you just entered the website? When i open it at first time, the UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT arrows will control the chrome scrollbar, and thats not the idea. Once i clic the menu the keynav works perfectly. What i want to do is bypass the clicking menu, so that right when i enter the site the arrows keys are fully functional. How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set focus on the menu element after you initialize:

```
$('#menu').menu().focus();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/focus